# How do I convert from Local Coordinates to Screen Space Coordinates in ARSCNView?

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, coordinate-systems, arkit

I want to get the corner coordinates of a plane that ARKit has identified into the `ARSCNView` screen coordinates.

I've started by adapting Apple's example for creating the planes, so I have a Plane class:

```
class Plane : SCNNode {

    var anchor : ARPlaneAnchor

    init(anchor : ARPlaneAnchor) {
        self.anchor = anchor
        super.init()

        self.geometry = SCNPlane(width: CGFloat(Float(anchor.extent.x)), height: CGFloat(anchor.extent.z))
        self.rotation = SCNVector4Make(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -Float.pi/2.0)
        let material = SCNMaterial()
        material.diffuse.contents = UIColor.yellow
        material.specular.contents = UIColor.white
        self.geometry?.firstMaterial = material
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("Error")
    }

    func update(anchor: ARPlaneAnchor) {
        self.anchor = anchor
        if let plane = self.geometry as? SCNPlane {
            plane.width = CGFloat(anchor.extent.x)
            plane.height = CGFloat(anchor.extent.z)
        }
    }
}
```

And the ARSCNViewDelegate methods in the view controller to identify and update it:

```
func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didAdd node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {
    if let planeAnchor = anchor as? ARPlaneAnchor {
        let plane = Plane(anchor: planeAnchor)
        node.addChildNode(plane)
        planes[planeAnchor] = plane
        print("plane = \(plane)")
    }  
}

func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didUpdate node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {
    if let planeAnchor = anchor as? ARPlaneAnchor {
        planes[planeAnchor]?.update(anchor: planeAnchor)
    }
}

func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didRemove node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {
    if let planeAnchor = anchor as? ARPlaneAnchor {
        planes.removeValue(forKey: planeAnchor)
    }
}
```

As I understand it, the plane has it's own local coordinate space in SceneKit, so I want to to just create 4 `SCNVector3` values, and convert them from the Plane's local space to the scene's world coordinate space, and from them, project them to the screen's space.

This is how I'm doing it:

```
   func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, updateAtTime time: TimeInterval) {
       for (_, aPlane) in planes {
           // Vectors representing the corners of the plane
           let maxX = aPlane.anchor.extent.x/2.0
           let minX = -maxX
           let minY = aPlane.anchor.extent.z/2.0
           let maxY = -minY

           var point1 = SCNVector3Make(minX, 0.0, minY)
           var point2 = SCNVector3Make(maxX, 0.0, minY)
           var point3 = SCNVector3Make(maxX, 0.0, maxY)
           var point4 = SCNVector3Make(minX, 0.0, maxY)
//         var point1 = SCNVector3Make(minX, minY, 0.0)
//         var point2 = SCNVector3Make(maxX, minY, 0.0)
//         var point3 = SCNVector3Make(maxX, maxY, 0.0)
//         var point4 = SCNVector3Make(minX, maxY, 0.0)

           print("initial nodes ------------------")
           print("point1 = \(point1)")
           print("point2 = \(point2)")
           print("point3 = \(point3)")
           print("point4 = \(point4)")

           // Get the root node and convert the coords from the plane's coord system
           let rootNode = sceneView.scene.rootNode
           point1 = rootNode.convertVector(point1, from: aPlane)
           point2 = rootNode.convertVector(point2, from: aPlane)
           point3 = rootNode.convertVector(point3, from: aPlane)
           point4 = rootNode.convertVector(point4, from: aPlane)

           print("first conversion nodes ------------------")
           print("point1 = \(point1)")
           print("point2 = \(point2)")
           print("point3 = \(point3)")
           print("point4 = \(point4)")

           // Finally, project them to the screen view
           point1 = sceneView.projectPoint(point1)
           point2 = sceneView.projectPoint(point2)
           point3 = sceneView.projectPoint(point3)
           point4 = sceneView.projectPoint(point4)
           print("final conversion nodes ------------------")
           print("point1 = \(point1)")
           print("point2 = \(point2)")
           print("point3 = \(point3)")
           print("point4 = \(point4)")
       }
   }
```

However, whatever I do, when I have a plane in full view, I still get coordinates outside the bounds of the view. I'm pretty sure it's something simple, but I've tried many combinations now.

Comment: Any progress on that one?